# Como enviar Push Notification para android e iphone com formulário processado por php?

Tags: php, push-notification

Alguém conhece um script em PHP, que funcione, para enviar msgs para GCM e APNS (android e iphone)? O usuário preenche form, o script PHP processa e envia para GCM e APNS. A partir dai segue a rotina natural de envio de push. Só preciso da parte PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>PHP é back-end, ou seja roda em um servidor HTTP nada tem a ver com android, ele nunca poderá controlar diretamente o smartphone, ou qualquer coisa.</s>

Deves aprender primeiramente a diferença de back-end e front-end, o que é servidor e o que é cliente, sabendo isso entenderá as camadas.

Não tem como resolver o problema sem saber se deseja enviar para múltiplos usuários e o que causa a chamada da notificação. O PHP não terá nada haver com esta ação diretamente, ele no máximo conterá um dado que seja um numero, string ou booleano e o app Android/iOS irá buscar essa url via http pra conferir os dados, após receber os dados o APP é quem fará o resto.

O `PushNotification` no Phonegap deve ficar algo como:

Será algo como:

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    android: {
        senderID: "12345679"
    },
    browser: {
        pushServiceURL: 'http://[minha url]/pagina.php'
    },
    ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: "true",
        sound: "true"
    },
    windows: {}
});

push.on('registration', function(data) {
    // data.registrationId
});

push.on('notification', function(data) {
    // data.message,
    // data.title,
    // data.count,
    // data.sound,
    // data.image,
    // data.additionalData
});

push.on('error', function(e) {
    // e.message
});
```

E para enviar a solicitação via GCM eu encontrei esse código semi-pronto [**gist**](https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017):

> **Nota:** a url para envio do GCM é https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

```
<?php

// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR-API-ACCESS-KEY-GOES-HERE' );


$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );

// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'    => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'      => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'   => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText' => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
    'data'             => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

### APN:

O APN é um pouco mais complexo, pois requer algumas configurações do servidor em alguns casos

### Solução 1 para o APN

Existe um repositório https://github.com/immobiliare/ApnsPHP, se for usar somente push e feedback irá irá precisar somente do OpenSSL, geralmente isso já vem ativado na maioria dos servidores:

- Requer PHP 5.3.0+ e suporte para OpenSSL, PCNTL, System V shared memory e semaphore, para configurar o servidor rode este comando (o PATH é opicional, e será comente necessário se o local do arquivo for diferente)

  ```
  ./configure --with-openssl[=PATH] --enable-pcntl --enable-sysvshm --enable-sysvsem
  ```
- Se pretende usar somente Push e o provedor de Feedback sem a parte do servidor então você irá precisar somente do OpenSSL:

  ```
  ./configure --with-openssl[=PATH]
  ```

Envio de push:

```
<?php

// Adjust to your timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

// Using Autoload all classes are loaded on-demand
require_once 'ApnsPHP/Autoload.php';

// Instantiate a new ApnsPHP_Push object
$push = new ApnsPHP_Push(
    ApnsPHP_Abstract::ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX,
    'server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem'
);

// Set the Provider Certificate passphrase
// $push->setProviderCertificatePassphrase('test');

// Set the Root Certificate Autority to verify the Apple remote peer
$push->setRootCertificationAuthority('entrust_root_certification_authority.pem');

// Connect to the Apple Push Notification Service
$push->connect();

// Instantiate a new Message with a single recipient
$message = new ApnsPHP_Message('1e82db91c7ceddd72bf33d74ae052ac9c84a065b35148ac401388843106a7485');

// Set a custom identifier. To get back this identifier use the getCustomIdentifier() method
// over a ApnsPHP_Message object retrieved with the getErrors() message.
$message->setCustomIdentifier("Message-Badge-3");

// Set badge icon to "3"
$message->setBadge(3);

// Set a simple welcome text
$message->setText('Hello APNs-enabled device!');

// Play the default sound
$message->setSound();

// Set a custom property
$message->setCustomProperty('acme2', array('bang', 'whiz'));

// Set another custom property
$message->setCustomProperty('acme3', array('bing', 'bong'));

// Set the expiry value to 30 seconds
$message->setExpiry(30);

// Add the message to the message queue
$push->add($message);

// Send all messages in the message queue
$push->send();

// Disconnect from the Apple Push Notification Service
$push->disconnect();

// Examine the error message container
$aErrorQueue = $push->getErrors();
if (!empty($aErrorQueue)) {
    var_dump($aErrorQueue);
}
```

Feedback:

```
<?php
// Adjust to your timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

// Using Autoload all classes are loaded on-demand
require_once 'ApnsPHP/Autoload.php';

// Instanciate a new ApnsPHP_Feedback object
$feedback = new ApnsPHP_Feedback(
    ApnsPHP_Abstract::ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX,
    'server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem'
);

// Connect to the Apple Push Notification Feedback Service
$feedback->connect();

$aDeviceTokens = $feedback->receive();
if (!empty($aDeviceTokens)) {
    var_dump($aDeviceTokens);
}

// Disconnect from the Apple Push Notification Feedback Service
$feedback->disconnect();
```

### Solução 2 para APN

Uma extensão (precisa instalar no servidor ou compilar lá) que facilita o desenvolvimento http://libcapn.org/php-apn/

- **Instalação com pecl:**

  Digite no terminal

  ```
  pecl install apn
  ```

  Ou

  ```
  cd php-apn
  pecl install package.xml
  ```
- Instalação manual:

  Digite no terminal:

  ```
  cd php-apn
  phpize
  ./configure
  make
  make install
  ```

Código envio do push:

```
// APNS contex
$apn = apn_init();
apn_set_array($apn, array(
      'certificate' => 'apns-dev-cert.pem',
      'private_key' => 'apns-dev-key.pem',
      'private_key_pass' => 'qwerty',
      'mode' => APN_SANDBOX
  ));

// Notification Payload context
$payload = apn_payload_init();
apn_payload_set_array($payload, array(
      'body' => 'This push was sent using PHP && php-apn',
      'sound' => 'default',
      'badge' => 34,
      'tokens' => array (
          'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
          'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'
      )
));
apn_payload_add_custom_property($payload, 'test', 56);

$error = NULL;
$errcode = 0;

// Opening Apple Push Notification Service connection...
if(apn_connect($apn, $error, $errcode)) {
    // and if ok, try send push notification....
    if(!apn_send($apn, $payload, $error, $errcode)) {
        echo 'Could not sent push notification: ' . $error;
    }
} else {
    echo 'Could not connected to Apple Push Notification Servece: ' . $error;
}

apn_close($apn);
apn_payload_free($payload);
apn_free($apn);
```

Código do serviço de Feedback:

```
// APNS contex
$apn = apn_init();
apn_set_array($apn, array(
      'certificate' => 'apns-dev-cert.pem',
      'private_key' => 'apns-dev-key.pem',
      'private_key_pass' => 'qwerty',
      'mode' => APN_SANDBOX
  ));

$error = NULL;
$errcode = 0;

if(apn_feedback_connect($apn, $error, $errcode)) {
    $tokens = apn_feedback($apn, $error, $errcode);
    if(!is_array($tokens)) {
        echo 'Failed to obtain device tokens: ' . $error;
    } else {
      foreach($tokens as $token) {
          echo 'Token: '.$token;
      }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Failed to connect to Apple Push Feedback Service: ' . $error;
}

apn_close($apn);
apn_free($apn);
```

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento, eu sei. Desenvolvo para web com PHP faz tempo. Mas estou desenvolvendo para mobile a menos tempo. Já tenho apps criados funcionando blz. Mas o que preciso no momento é acrescentar um formulário numa aplicação web onde o cliente irá definir a mensagem que quer enviar para o app que está instalado nos smartphone dos clientes. Naturalmente esse formulário será processado por um script php que enviará o push para android e iphone, via GCM e APNS.

Comment: @RondaNetbr depois da sua edição ficou claro, mas antes dava a entender uma coisa totalmente diferente, todavia parece uma boa pergunta, espero que o código lhe ajude, eu corrigi uma coisa que ficou faltando nele (o echo).

Comment: Valeu @GuilhermeNascimento. Acho que irá  me ajudar muito. Abs.

Comment: GCM tá datado, o FCM agora o suplantou e se não me engano é ligeiramente menos difícil de usar

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado opa, obrigado, vou atualizar a resposta assim que tiver uma oportunidade.